A polynomial recurrence relation, what does it solve?
A normal recurrence relation looks like so >
$$0 = \sum_{k=0}^N c_{k}a_{n-k}$$
Often by convention we choose $c_0 = -1$ and rewrite it to arrive at the probably more well-known expression >
$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^N c_{k}a_{n-k}$$
How can we solve recurrence relations with polynomials?
Or rather : which functions can we model using polynomial recurrence relations.
First of all. What do I mean with polynomial recurrence relations?
$$a_n = \sum_{l=1}^p\sum_{k=1}^N c_{kl}{(a_{n-k})}^l$$
As you may infer from my choice of sum limits : In other words what I am after is modelling or predicting the current value from linear combinations of previous values and their lower powers.
Which families of functions would allow themselves to be described like this?
